# Read File and Print It Out in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python. 
I want to read a file. The contents in the file are:

```
17 2 3 0

5 16 11 7

9 8 0 6

0 14 17 1
```

I want to read and print it out like this:

```
aList= [[17,2,3,0],
        [5,16,11,7],
        [9,8,0,6],
        [0,14,17,1]]
```

Here is my code:

```
file = open("file.txt","r")
aList=[]
for line in file:
aList.append(line.strip().split(","))
```

Now the error is the file not found and cannot print it out.

Comment: Check the file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
aList = []
with open('file.txt') as handle:
    for text in handle:
        aList.append(text.strip().split())

print(list(filter(None, aList)))
```

output is:
`[['17', '2', '3', '0'], ['5', '16', '11', '7'], ['9', '8', '0', '6'], ['0', '14', '17', '1']]`

Comment: How about I want it print as integer?

Comment: `aList.append([int(i) for i in text.strip().split()])` use this instead of `aList.append(text.strip().split())` in my answer. That should get you integers

Comment: OK, than you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter:

```
with open(filname,'r') as f:
   print([line.split() for line in f if line.split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
    flread=open('path/to/file/filename','r')
    for i in flread.readlines():
        for k in i.split(' '):
             a.append(int(k))
             a=[]
        b.append(a)
     print(b)
```

output: `[[17, 2, 3, 0], [5, 16, 11, 7], [9, 8, 0, 6], [0, 14, 17, 1]]`

Answer (score -1):

The file path will be taken relative to your <strike>python script (`.py` file)</strike> current working directory. You need to either keep your `file.txt` in the same directory as your <strike>`.py` file</strike> cwd or use the absolute path of your `file.txt` for `open()` function like `open('/path/to/your/file.txt')` (assuming you're running Linux) or `open('C:\\path\\to\\your\\file.txt')` (windows).

Comment: the file path is relative to the current working directory, not to the script

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers sorry didn't know that. updated my post.